# Converting string to list in R

Tags: r

I have a csv file with one of the columns containing list data, like so,

[image]

After I read the file in R (read csv), the "combined" column has string data type. I want to be able to get it as a list. For instance, in python we would do something like,

```
df.combined.apply(literal_eval)
```

How do I do the same in R?

Comment: `literal_eval` exists almost exactly like this in R; however, it won’t work here since the syntax isn’t valid R. And it’s a bad idea in both R and Python due to various reasons (security, performance, conceptually). Instead, I would suggest manually parsing the strings, it’s trivial: just remove the `[` and `]` characters and split the rest by `,`, then remove the quotes. Or use regular expressions. — One last remark, the Python code is more verbose than necessary: `lambda x: f(x)` can be abbreviated to just `f`. That is: `df.combined.apply(literal_eval)`.

Comment: Is it JSON format?  If so, you can use `jsonlite::parse_json()` to parse the entries one at a time.

Comment: @user2554330 No, JSON requires double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Konrad's answer, this is what I ended up doing:

```
step1= str_replace_all(text, "\\[", "")
step2= str_replace_all(step1, "\\]", "")
step3= str_replace_all(step2, "'", "")
step4= as.list(el(strsplit(step3, ",")))
```

PS: Thank you for pointing to the security aspect about `literal_eval`.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to lapply through the column:

```r
goid_list <- lapply(df$combined, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, "', '")))
```

this gives you a list of character vectors. You will probably retain the square brackets in the first and secong GO-ID, so you might want to remove them with a `gsub` either within the lapply or a new lapply:

```r
lapply(goid_list, function(x) gsub("['", "", gsub("']", "", x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do :

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(combined=list(reticulate::py_eval(combined)))
```